# Are there any developers here who do logic operations on hex in their head?

Tags: hex

Are there any developers here who do logic operations on hex in their head?

If so, how did you internalise this ability.  Do you still mentally convert to binary as part of the process?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: I've stopped doing almost all math in my head. Too prone to error, too easy to locate a calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first started Hex I would always try to do it in my head but as Cody stated it is near impossible not to make a mistake that way so your best bet is to stick with the trusted old calculator.